# mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation() doesn't return anything

Tags: java, android, location

i'm trying to create a simple app to show gps location and i always get an exception returned 
this exception

```
Log.w(TAG, "getLastLocation:exception", task.getException());showSnackbar(getString(R.string.no_location_detected));
```

it seems as there's no last location registered but i know for sure there's
i tried using googleservice api with no luck as well
my layout is simple only a text view and an input view with no function yet so it can be ignored for the purposes of this question

my java activity

```
/**
  * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
*/
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
/**
 * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
 * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
 */
private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;
private static final String TAG = FullscreenActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;

/**
 * Provides the entry point to the Fused Location Provider API.
 */
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

/**
 * Represents a geographical location.
 */
protected Location mLastLocation;

private String mLatitudeLabel;
private String mLongitudeLabel;
private TextView mLatitudeText;
private TextView mLongitudeText;
private String provider;
/**
 * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
 * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
 */
private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

/**
 * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
 * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
 */
private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
private View mContentView;
private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

        // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
        // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
        // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
};
private View mControlsView;
private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Delayed display of UI elements
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.show();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};
private boolean mVisible;
private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        hide();
    }
};
/**
 * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
 * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
 * while interacting with activity UI.
 */
private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (AUTO_HIDE) {
            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    mVisible = true;
    mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

    mLatitudeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.latitude_label);
    mLongitudeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.longitude_label);
    mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.latitude_text));
    mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.longitude_text));

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toggle();
        }
    });

    // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
    // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
    // while interacting with the UI.
    findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
            // get EditText by id and store it into "inputTxt"
            EditText inputTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
            onStart();
            // Store EditText - Input in variable

            String typedText = inputTxt.getText().toString();
            Log.v(typedText, "index");
        }
    });




}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    if (!checkPermissions()) {
        requestPermissions();
    } else {
        getLastLocation();
    }
}

/**
 * Provides a simple way of getting a device's location and is well suited for
 * applications that do not require a fine-grained location and that do not need location
 * updates. Gets the best and most recent location currently available, which may be null
 * in rare cases when a location is not available.
 * <p>
 * Note: this method should be called after location permission has been granted.
 */

@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
private void getLastLocation() {
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                        mLastLocation = task.getResult();

                        mLatitudeText.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s: %f",
                                mLatitudeLabel,
                                mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
                        mLongitudeText.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s: %f",
                                mLongitudeLabel,
                                mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
                        Log.v(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s: %f",
                                mLatitudeLabel,
                                mLastLocation.getLatitude()),"location");
                    } else {

                        Log.w(TAG, "getLastLocation:exception", task.getException());
                        showSnackbar(getString(R.string.no_location_detected));
                    }
                }
            });
}

/**
 * Shows a {@link Snackbar} using {@code text}.
 *
 * @param text The Snackbar text.
 */
private void showSnackbar(final String text) {
    View container = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
    if (container != null) {
        Snackbar.make(container, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Shows a {@link Snackbar}.
 *
 * @param mainTextStringId The id for the string resource for the Snackbar text.
 * @param actionStringId   The text of the action item.
 * @param listener         The listener associated with the Snackbar action.
 */
private void showSnackbar(final int mainTextStringId, final int actionStringId,
                          View.OnClickListener listener) {
    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
            getString(mainTextStringId),
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction(getString(actionStringId), listener).show();
}

/**
 * Return the current state of the permissions needed.
 */
private boolean checkPermissions() {
    int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

private void startLocationPermissionRequest() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(FullscreenActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
            REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
}

private void requestPermissions() {
    boolean shouldProvideRationale =
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

    // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
    // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
    if (shouldProvideRationale) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");

        showSnackbar(R.string.permission_rationale, android.R.string.ok,
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Request permission
                        startLocationPermissionRequest();
                    }
                });

    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
        // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
        // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
        // previously and checked "Never ask again".
        startLocationPermissionRequest();
    }
}

/**
 * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
            // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
            // receive empty arrays.
            Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission granted.
            getLastLocation();
        } else {
            // Permission denied.

            // Notify the user via a SnackBar that they have rejected a core permission for the
            // app, which makes the Activity useless. In a real app, core permissions would
            // typically be best requested during a welcome-screen flow.

            // Additionally, it is important to remember that a permission might have been
            // rejected without asking the user for permission (device policy or "Never ask
            // again" prompts). Therefore, a user interface affordance is typically implemented
            // when permissions are denied. Otherwise, your app could appear unresponsive to
            // touches or interactions which have required permissions.
            showSnackbar(R.string.permission_denied_explanation, R.string.settings,
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(
                                    Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                            intent.setData(uri);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}








@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
    // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
    // are available.
    delayedHide(100);
}

private void toggle() {

    hide();

}

private void hide() {
    // Hide UI first
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.hide();

    mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mVisible = false;

    // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
}

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private void show() {
    // Show the system bar
    mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    mVisible = true;

    // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
}

/**
 * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
 * previously scheduled calls.
 */
private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
}

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
```

}

Comment: What does the taskException return?

Comment: it says "No location detected. Make Sure location is enabled on your device" and location is of course enabled

Comment: Can you run it and provide your logcat?

Comment: @H.Brooks I found a wierd behaviour same as Yassine. Problem is even if we allow the location permission. our gps icon is disabled if we see from notification panel. Thats y the problem occurs. Please comment if you found any solution. I am facing same scenario.

Comment: @Yasssine If location from settings is disabled then it will give this error. But if we allow location from settings and then run the app it will run

Comment: @H.Brooks I have implemented SettingsClient here to solve the issue : http://github.com/askfortricks/FusedLocationProviderClient